# Facebook Send flyout clipping issues

Tags: event-handling, facebook-like, clipping, flyout

I have a problem with the flyout generated by the Facebook Send button. After clicking the "Send" button the flyout is generated and displayed behind some elements. Obscuring the buttons in the flyout.

I read that this is because of a parent element with the overflow:hidden style. However, I cannot remove this attribute since it will mess up the rest of my sites layout.

I tried to dynamically remove the overflow:hidden attribute upon clicking the Send button (Accepting the layout mess if someone actually uses the send button). Using the following code:

> FB.Event.subscribe("message.send", function(response) { //Remove the
>   overflow:hidden styling here });

Unfortunately this event only fires upon actually sending the flyout form, which is too late as need to take action as soon as the button is pressed that shows the flyout.

Could anyone tell me how to bind an onclick event to the "Send" button or how to reposition the flyout completely. Or perhaps there is an alternate solution I have not yet considered.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if this will help, i seen on a site where they had the button in a container and on mouse over the container changed to a fixed position which kept for the fly out form from being clipped.  Then on mouseout the container when back to its relative position.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed position might work for some, but for most it will mess up your layout.

What worked for me is to take off any `overflow: auto` higher up in your CSS.

I did that and it works great!